# Continue ssh from previous state

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm accessing through ssh to a linux box. I was simply updateing the packages with yum update. I then disconnected but when I connnected again with ssh using the same account I couldn't now if the update process had already finished.

How can I know the status of tasks I've started before disconnecting when I reconnect to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can verify if anything is still running using

```
ps -aux | grep yum
```

But I'm pretty sure it will be killed as soon as you get disconnected.

If you need to run something after you leave use [nohup](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nohup-execute-commands-after-you-exit-from-a-shell-prompt.html)

Answer (score 9):

What you really want to do is run this in `screen`.

Every day when I come into the office, I ssh to my development / db server and run `screen -RD`, which reconnects my session as if I had never disconnected. You should be able to `yum install screen`.

See http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2004/3/9/16838/14935 to start, and http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/ for a comprehensive reference.

Answer (score 1):

Use `screen`. Just start `screen`, do your stuff and when you got disconnected, run: `screen -r` or `screen -Dr`.